# karma-typescript cannot find module

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-runner

I have a very small project that I am trying to set up unit tests for. The project *compiles fine when using `tsc` directly*, however, I am getting the following Typescript compilation errors when attempting to execute tests which use the karma-typescript framework:

**ERRORS:**

> ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/drawing/canvas.model.ts(1,23):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'utils'.
>
> ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/models/grid.model.ts(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'utils'.
>
> ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/utils/specs/obj.utils.spec.ts(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'utils'.

---

**PROJECT STRUCTURE:**
I've got a project set up that is structured as such:

```
|-dist/
|-node_modules/
|-src/
| |
| |-drawing/
| | |
| | |-canvas.model.ts
| |    ________________________________
| |   | import { Utils } from 'utils'; |  Karma Fails (tsc is fine)
| |    --------------------------------
| |
| |-models/
| | |
| | |-grid.model.ts
| |    ________________________________
| |   | import { Utils } from 'utils'; |  Karma Fails (tsc is fine)
| |    --------------------------------
| | 
| |-utils/
| | |
| | |-index.ts
| | |  _________________________
| | | | export module Utils {}  |
| | |  -------------------------
| | |
| | |-specs/
| | | |
| | | |-obj.utils.spec.ts
| | |    ________________________________
| | |   | import { Utils } from 'utils'; |  Karma Fails (tsc is fine)
| | |    --------------------------------
| | |
|-karma.config.js
|-tsconfig.json
|-package.json
```

---

It's clear to me that there is a discrepancy between my tsconfig.json file and the compiler settings used internally for karma-typescript. Here is how I have both of those files structured. According to the [documentation for karma-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript), there should be a couple of options that I can configure in my karma.conf file that would tell karma-typescript to respect my settings in my Typescript config file, namely the `"paths"` property, which is where I have specified to Typescript where to look for my `utils` module.

**KARMA.CONF.JS**

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Mar 31 2017 16:42:11 GMT-0700 (PDT)
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],
    // Plugins
    plugins: [
      'karma-spec-reporter',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
      'karma-typescript'
    ],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [{
      pattern: "./src/**/*.ts"
    }],
    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: ['**/*.spec.js'],

    // Karma Typescript compiler options
    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      bundlerOptions: {
        resolve: {
          directories: ["src", "node_modules", "src/utils"]
        }
      }
    },
    compilerOptions: {
      module: 'commonjs',
      moduleResolution: 'node',
      paths: {
        'utils': ['./src/utils'], 'utils/*': ['./src/utils/*']
      }
    },
    tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
    },
    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'spec', "karma-typescript"],
    // web server port
    port: 9876,
    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,
    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,
    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,
    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

---

Here is my Typescript config file. Note that I am registering the `"utils"` in the `"paths"` portion of the tsconfig file, which assists in the Typescript compiler's [module resolution process](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). This works fine with normal Typescript compilation, but that is probably because my Typescript compiler is actually respecting the settings in my tsconfig file. I am using **Typescript 2.0.10**. But it appears that karma-typescript is using **Typescript 2.2.2**, which could be the potential source of the error. I'll have to run my compiler against that version to see if I can generate the same error.

**TSCONFIG.JSON**

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "paths": {
      "utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"],
      "utils": ["./src/utils"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDirs": ["./dist", "."]
  },
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./dist", "**/*.d.ts"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm decent with Typescript but pretty new to Karma. I've been scouring documentation for about 2 days now trying to get these simple unit tests running, but to no avail. Not with the way I've got my paths structured at least. Any help would be appreciated!

---

**UPDATE:**
I tried updating my local installation of Typescript to **2.2.2**, to match the Karma-Typescript's version which is also **2.2.2**. Same error, same scenario - my local version compiles fine, but the Karma-Typescript version balks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a tiny error in the Karma config, the `compilerOptions` and `tsconfig` properties should be inside the `karmaTypescriptConfig` property.

Given your project structure example, here's a minimal working configuration example for both `tsc` and `karma-typescript`:

**Karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        frameworks: ["jasmine", "karma-typescript"],

        files: [
            { pattern: "src/**/*.ts" }
        ],

        karmaTypescriptConfig: {
            compilerOptions: {
                module: "commonjs"
            },
            tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
        },

        preprocessors: {
            "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
        },

        reporters: ["progress", "kjhtml", "spec", "karma-typescript"],

        browsers: ["Chrome"]
    });
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "paths": {
            "utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"],
            "utils": ["./src/utils"]
        },
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

I tested this using `typescript@2.2.2` and `karma-typescript@3.0.0`.

Also, please note that `karma-typescript` only has Typescript as a dev dependency, letting you use any Typescript version from 1.6.2 and up :)

Comment: Thank you!! That fixed it. :)

Comment: I wonder if "module" could also be set to "es6" in "karma.conf.js" to make it consistent with "tsconfig.json".

Comment: @user130685 technically Karma can test es6 module code (i.e., inject the code into the runner using `<script type="module>` tags) but then you have a different problem: non-relative imports break.  Most people who write ES6 code use Node-style imports and let a bundler resolve them for you, but Karma doesn't do that (out of the box, at least).

Answer (score 4):

I had an error `Error: Unable to resolve module [...] from [...]` because of my custom module paths in `tsconfig.json`. And this is my solution for that problem:

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions" {
    ...
    "paths": { // My custom module path
        "parchment/blot/*": ["node_modules/parchment/dist/src/blot/*"],
        "parchment/attributor/*": ["node_modules/parchment/dist/src/attributor/*"]
    },
    ...


// karma.conf.js
...
karmaTypescriptConfig: {
    tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
    bundlerOptions: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'parchment/dist/src/attributor': './node_modules/parchment/dist/parchment.js',
                'parchment/dist/src/blot/abstract': './node_modules/parchment/dist/parchment.js'
            },
            extensions: ['.js'] // Extension that causes the error
        }
    }
}
...
```

As you see, `bundlerOptions.resolve` is the key to the solution.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you can point `karma-typescript` directly at a `tsconfig.json` instead of duplicating a bunch of options in both places.